# Reading data in different formats using unpack in python

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python and have just started working somewhere. Have been trying to understand a piece of code that was written here by a developer who left and I haven't been able to figure things about.

Basically, I am acquainted with what unpack() does, but the format that has been used in some places leaves me bewildered!

`var1, var2, var3, var4 = struct.unpack('!6xBB4xI4xI', data)`

is the assignment statement for 4 variables. Now this is what I have figured out about the format being used to unpack and I believe is correct:-

'x': separation of value (padding bit as pointed out by @shx2 in the answer below)

!6: read the 7th character from start (start being at index 0) in BIG-ENDIAN format

I: unsigned integer

```
Now, I haven't been able to figure out the formats:-
BB4 - does that mean read 8 bytes (as the B stands for unsigned char, so BB could mean 2 sets of unsigned char)?
I4 - reading 4 bytes and getting the integer value!
```

*My interpretation about the other 2 formats might very well be incorrect as well - I am just trying to figure it out from the python online doc and the data that I see during debug. Please correct me wherever I might be wrong.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in Big Endian format, `struct.unpack('!6xBB4xI4xI', data)` means:

`6`: 6 pad bytes
`B`: One unsigned char
`B`: One unsigned char 
`4`: Pad Bytes
`I`: One Unsigned Int
`4`: Pad bytes
`I`: One Unsigned Int

In total the structure has 24 bytes

Answer (score 2):

You are way off... Read the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct-format-strings).

`!` is network order (= big-endian).

`x` is pad byte.

And I'm sure you can figure out the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I actually meant the same about padding bit, just didn't quote the same word :) Could you help me as to what would a BB4 and I4 mean (B being unsigned char and I an unsigned int)? Ihave updated my question with the complete assignment statement as well - as you can see, 4 variables are getting values assinged; is that dictated by the padding byte 'x'?